# What is the R markdown equivalent to LaTeX \texttt?

Tags: r, latex, markdown

What is the R markdown equivalent to LaTeX `\texttt`?

With this MWE:

````
---
title: "A test"
author: "Alessandro"
date: "February 19, 2016"
output: pdf_document
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
d<-data.frame(product_name=c('d','a','b','c')) # what to write here to get a typewriter font?
```

Product names are: `r sort(d$product_name)`.
````

I get this pdf:

[image]

While I would like to get the output from this [`.tex` file](https://www.overleaf.com/4388270pqccss#/13083824/)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{A test}
\author{Alessandro}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Product names are: \texttt{a, b, c, d}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no native markdown way of doing this. But when the output format is `pdf_document`, the rmarkdown equivalent of `\texttt` is `\texttt` itself:

```
Product names are: \texttt{`r sort(d$product_name)`}.
```

Rmarkdown uses latex under the hood to compile to pdf, so most raw latex command should work as expected.

The same is true for html output :

```
Product names are: <tt>`r sort(d$product_name)`</tt>.
```